# Compiz on Lubuntu

Tags: compiz, lubuntu

I installed `compiz` on my `lubuntu` and some other packages like compiz-plugins and....

When I run `compiz --replace` all window borders (title bar etc.) go away.

What's the problem? What should I do? How can I run it correctly?

I also run `xcompmgr -n`, so I can have transparency on some apps like `synapse` and `terminal`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer in [this video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7PRXBOV7Fqs):

The answer is in the following file:

```
~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/desktop.conf
```

change the value of `windows_manager/command` from `openbox` to `compiz ccp`.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that you have to configure Compiz so that it works with Lubuntu.

You need CompizConfig Settings Manager (CCSM) to change the settings for Compiz. It is available from the Ubuntu repos. You can use Ubuntu Software Center to install it.

<strike>I tried to find a guide to get Compiz working correctly for Lubuntu, but I can't seem to find one right now.</strike> Found a guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompositeManager

To get window borders, search in CCSM for "decoration". Then check-mark "Window Decoration" that shows up.

Comment: I already installed CCSM, but I still have the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm putting this here for those like me, who got this far and ended up with no minimize and maximize on windows borders. I found the solution on the Arch Linux forums:

> Installing the stable version of compiz got gtk-window-decorator working > again, but now I have no minimize or maximize buttons on any gtk theme > (only a close button), and gtk-window-decorator throws me*
>
> ```
> (gtk-window-decorator:23942): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid uninstantiatable type '(null)' in cast to 'WnckWindow'
> gtk-window-decorator: Ignoring unknown or already-used button name "appmenu"
> ```
>
> EDIT: This problem was solved by running
>
> ```
> gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout "'menu:minimize,maximize,close'"
> ```
>
> for future reference to anyone who stumbles across this post. Thanks again for the help!

Original post [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=188581), by Ekkoria.

Comment: +1, nice answer, and good formatting! Nice to see someone referencing appropriately as well.

Answer (score 0):

I always use `compiz` on Lubuntu.

First, I opened `synaptic-package-manager`, installed `compiz-plugins-extra`, `compiconfig-settings-manager`, and `fusion-icon`. `fusion-icon` is very important.

Next,I opened `default applications for LXsession,`Autostart` tag, and added this line.

```
@/usr/bin/compiz --replace
```

And log-out/in. That's all.

If you install `mate-desktop-environment` and some themes on Lubuntu, You can customize appearance and change window manager to compiz, I think you'll be able to get some other window borders on Lubuntu, too.