# Shortcut keys doesn't work after installing compiz on Lubuntu

Tags: compiz, shortcut-keys, lubuntu, shortcuts

I have Lubuntu on my laptop. I installed `compiz` with many fighting recently :).

Now compiz works but shortcut keys I defined in Lubuntu don't work anymore. I defined those shortcuts in this file:

```
  ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml (maybe lxde-rc.xml in other lxde enabled distros)
```

What should I do now?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Have you figured it out?

Answer (score 1):

Your own answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420975/compiz-on-lubuntu) indicates you are not running Openbox anymore!

> change the value of windows_manager/command from openbox to compiz ccp

That is why shortcuts defined in `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` will not work as long as Openbox is not window manager.

Comment: Thanks, but I knew that. Actually my question is how can I have those shortcuts enabled in compiz again?